# how to set border radius for stacked bar in highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Hi I am trying to set border radius for stacked bar with two items using

borderRadiusTopLeft: '50%',
borderRadiusTopRight: '50%',
borderRadiusBottomLeft: '50%',
borderRadiusBottomRight: '50%',

which is working good if both the values are >1

issue is when one of the value is 0

I need both sides with radius even if values is 0,

Please find the attachment for graph.

can someone help me please.

[image]

Comment: Instead of setting the children elements' `border-radius`, why not set the parents'?

Comment: if I add to parent getting border radius for each bar in stackbar

Comment: Could you reproduce your current attempt on some online editor which I could work on?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the parent's `border-radius`, this works for me:

```css
.bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bar > * {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.red {
  background-color: #E37273;
  flex: var(--red);
}

.blue {
  background-color: #29D0CE;
  flex: var(--blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="bar" style="--red: 0; --blue: 8;">
  <span class="red"></span>
  <span class="blue">8</span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="bar" style="--red: 5; --blue: 3;">
  <span class="red">5</span>
  <span class="blue">3</span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="bar" style="--red: 8; --blue: 0;">
  <span class="red">8</span>
  <span class="blue"></span>
</div>
```